# What is the technical term for glosses on a text that disagree with the text?

Tags: terminology, text-classification, philology

What is the technical term for glosses on a text that disagree with the text?

For example, in Hebrew we tend to use the term השגות to describe Raabad's "objections" to Alfasi's and Maimonides' opera, but is there a more elegant term that describes this concept? How would you say this in linguistic terms?

Comment: I don't think that there is a *linguistic* term for this. But historians often deal with manuscript pages that have different text layers by different authors, maybe they have some specific terminology for that.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica I'm pretty sure there is a technical term for this because I've come across it before. I just can't remember what it is.

Comment: There may be a technical term, it may just not be in use in **linguistics** but in history, theology, or another discipline like that.

Answer (score -4):

*Occasionally glossing, glossing mistake, glossing error.*
There no special technical term for this. But there are citates, that describe this phenomenon as 'occasionally glossing'. Other two are translation of the Hebrew term.

Next is strictly outside:

Firstly, my thoughts were about this phenomenon:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_prose

Upd: @jogloran There no connection, except my first understanding the 'glosses' as just 'words'. Not as annotation. Purple prose is situation where a part of words disagree with the text.

Upd2:@jogloran Yes, you are right if we speak about the purple prose. But if be honest I remembered not the purple prose (for me it was just a naming of the wiki-article) but purple passages: parts of a text, that disagree with the text in it's manner, stylistics. The situation where the plain texs consist extravagant parts. Maybe I still misunderstand it, but..

Comment: How is purple prose relevant to this discussion? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry, but aside from being irrelevant, you’ve also managed to misunderstand what “purple prose” means.